# IS OF TYPE generates an exception

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I read about [IS OF TYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions014.htm) and I expected that it should return TRUE, FALSE or NULL.

I have two object types:

```
CREATE TYPE o1 AS OBJECT ( id NUMBER );
/
CREATE TYPE o2 AS OBJECT ( id NUMBER );
/
```

When I run the code below, everything is OK.

```
DECLARE
  type1 o1;
BEGIN
   type1 := o1(id=>1); 

   if (type1 IS OF (o1)) then
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('type1 is o1');                    
   END if;  
END;
/
```

But when I try to run:

```
DECLARE
  type1 o1;
BEGIN
   type1 := o1(id=>1); 

   if (type1 IS OF (o2)) then
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('type1 is o1');                    
   END if;  
END;
/
```

I received the following exceptions

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 21:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 6, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

In the documentation there isn't clear explanation, should I catch exception if something is of the wrong type? Or, should I expect false in the IF condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have declared your variable as `O1` type then you can use `is of [type]` condition to test only whether your variable is of `o1` type or is of `o1`'s subtype. Here is an example(variables must be instantiated):

```
 -- base type  
 SQL> create or replace type o1 as object(
  2    prop number
  3  )not final;
  4  /

Type created

-- O1's subtype
SQL> create or replace type o2 under o1(
  2    prop1 number
  3  );
  4  /

-- test if the  l_o1 is of O1 type
SQL> declare
  2    l_o1  o1;
  3  begin
  4    l_o1 := o1(prop=>1);
  5    if l_o1 is of (o1)
  6    then
  7      dbms_output.put_line('Yes');
  8    else
  9      dbms_output.put_line('No');
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

Yes

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

-- test if the  l_o1 is of O2 type
SQL> declare
  2    l_o1  o1;
  3  begin
  4    l_o1 := o1(prop=>1);
  5    if l_o1 is of (o2)
  6    then
  7      dbms_output.put_line('Yes');
  8    else
  9      dbms_output.put_line('No');
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

No

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed


-- test if the  l_o2 is of O2 type

SQL> declare
  2    l_o2  o2;
  3  begin
  4    l_o2 := o2(prop=>1, prop1 => 1);
  5    if l_o2 is of (o2)
  6    then
  7      dbms_output.put_line('Yes');
  8    else
  9      dbms_output.put_line('No');
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

Yes

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

**Update**:

[Take a look at this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#i470492) to get more information about `is of[type]`. Usually data type of a variable is known at compile time, but if you have to deal with dynamic typing you may look at `anydata`(object data type). Here is a simple example:

```
 SQL> declare
  2    l_o1 o1;
  3  
  4    -- Here is a procedure(for the sake of simplicity has not
  5    -- been written as a schema object)
  6    -- that doesn't not know
  7    -- variable of what dada type will be passed in
  8    -- at compile time;
  9    procedure DoSomething(p_var anydata)
 10    is
 11    begin
 12      case p_var.gettypename
 13        when 'HR.O1'
 14        then dbms_output.put_line('O1 data type. Do something');
 15        when 'HR.O2'
 16        then dbms_output.put_line('O2 data type. Do something');
 17      else
 18        dbms_output.put_line('Unknown data type');
 19      end case;
 20    end;
 21  
 22  begin
 23    l_o1 := o1(prop =>  1);
 24    DoSomething(anydata.ConvertObject(l_o1));
 25  end;
 26  /

O1 data type. Do something

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: Thank you (this I know -  but would like to check for any type), strange for me, in this case documentation isn't so clear. Is there any other alternative (I know possibility of cast to anytpe an then get name which could be compared with user_types view) ?

Comment: Yes I wrote about this solution but I think there is something ease like IS OF. If someone know other solution please write, this (semi)solve my question. Thank you.